# Angular 2: How do i put an image on a canvas inside a loop?

Tags: html, angular

I'm on a project written by beginners, now i have a week to optimize some slow processes.

**Context:**
At the moment, there is picklist with PrimeNg that gets filled with products. Each product has a base64 string that gets converted to an image that gets shown per product.
[Here is what the picklist looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB5A4.png).

**Problem:**
There are so many products that it takes quit a lot of time to convert all the images and display something. I think it's already a bad idea to use base64 string for so much content and i can't afford a big rework.
(I read in another thread that drawing on a canvas could save some workload)

So how does it look like?

**SelectProductComponent.html**:

```
<p-picklist [source]="products">
  <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
      <img src="{{getImage(product)}}" style="max-width: 100%">
       ...
```

***SelectProductComponent*.ts**:

```
  getImage(product: Product) {
    if (product.image != null) {
      image.src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + product.image;
    }
    return 'assets/no-image-icon.png';
  }
```

---

**What i'm trying**
It is probably possible to use a canvas instead? I tried to transform it to something like this:

```
<p-picklist [source]="products">
  <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
      <canvas class="col-md-2" #myCanvas id='displayImage'></canvas> //Can i pass the product here?
       ...
```

***SelectProductComponent*.ts**:

```
  @ViewChild('myCanvas')
  myCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.context = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
  }

  getImage(product: Product) { // How do i pass the product to the canvas element?
    if (product.image != null) {
      // I don't know
    }
    return 'assets/no-image-icon.png';
  }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I doubt if that will help performance- and also introduces other issues (image responsiveness etc). Your issue might more likely be from the method call inside your template. Can you put a console call at the top of getImage and check how many times it gets called..?

Comment: Hi @MikeOne thanks for answering. 
The amount of calls depends on the category you click on. Not sure how i can count how many times it get called since the console will give output for every detection change? I wrote a console.log(x);  with x incrementing for every call and it goes op to 5500.
If i look in the network tab, i can see up to 370 requests done to fetch the images one by one. I guess that's the method call?

Comment: So that function is called on every detection cycle - however, you’re not actually doing that much in there so shouldn’t be a real problem. You’ll probably can improve performance significantly by only loading images the user can see? So implement incremental loading based on scroll for example..?

Comment: I'm going with that option! Thank you for your help @MikeOne!